# Spotlight regular expression shows twitter and movie suggestion

Tags: mac, macos-sierra, spotlight

This is a really bizarre thing... but here goes. I was using Spotlight as a temporary copy/paste scratch pad so that I didn't have to have a TextEdit window open. I am working on a regular expression (code), and pasted it into Spotlight for quick side-by-side comparison to something I found on StackOverflow.

This is what Spotlight came up with for suggestions:

[image: regex Spotlight madness]

It links to [Dave Rutledge's Twitter](https://twitter.com/davidroutledge) and Axwell Ingrosso's Ibiza (which is not actually a link to a page). What is going on behind the scenes for Spotlight to pull up such specific, yet bizarre results in the quick preview?

OS X version is 10.12.6 if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your system preferences then click on spotlight icon in system preferences and uncheck other, bookmarks & history. Done.

Comment: What question are you answering?  The question I'm reading seems to be asking to explain a behavior; it's not asking for any specific *different* behavior.

Comment: @DonHatch If the user follows this steps then these strange things won't appear anymore cause if this options are enabled then spotlight indexes everything on/off the mac and shows it on your spotlight search